# Why laravel homested is prefered? What it actually does?

Tags: laravel-5, vagrant, virtualbox, homestead

I am new in laravel. In documentation, homestead is preferred to use. I have used composer way to install the project and run the server from CLI. I have also used virtual host to serve my projects. I understand that homestead will make my work easy but still I don't understand that :

1. What is vagrant?
2. What is homestead?
3. What they actually do in back-end?

For me its difficult to install vagrant or homestead. I tried to install but had many errors may be I don't know the exact way of installation. 
I feel more easiness in running project from CLI. But I also need to know about these and if they are better then I want to start using them.
Before that, I want to know to get good understanding of above mentioned  things. 
If someone can explain the difference and other functionalities then kindly do it. I need to know more about it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually far from what you think of it to be. **Vagrant** is a development box. It uses well-known providers like *Virtualbox* and *VMWare* to setup a virtual machine on your host, which is the system you're currently using, and then provides easy to manage configuration file to configure your box. For more information on vagrant you can refer to it's [documentation](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/). vagrant boxes can be discovered using [Atlas vagrant cloud](https://atlas.hashicorp.com/boxes/search?vagrantcloud=1).

**Laravel/Homestead** is a vagrant box, which can be installed manually or through vagrant CLI. The box is packed with a bunch of useful stuff, including an OS (Ubuntu), LAMP, Nginx, and etc. For more info refer to [Laravel docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead).

Laravel team generated some useful scripts along with a `YAML configuration parser` which makes vagrant configuration even simpler. You can refer to both [Homestead documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/homestead) or [laravel/homestead github page](https://github.com/laravel/homestead) for more info.

Last but not least is what you actually gain using them. Let's say your a pro developer working in a team and you want all your team mates to have the same development configuration as you do. That's one thing you'll achieve using vagrant. You want to mess up with you environment and rollback in a matter of seconds, that's another advantage. and even if you're a solo developer who's just starting to learn, it's a good thing to keep your host OS clean at all time. Changes made to the virtual machine is isolated from your host OS. For more info on the uses you can read [Why vagrant article](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/why-vagrant/) in vagrant documentations or [google it!](https://www.google.com/search?q=vmware%20&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8&client=firefox-b-ab#q=why%20virtualization%20for%20development&*)

Comment: Anybody else who know something useful?